# Why should I assign nil when declaring a variable instead of giving it a base value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been doing a couple of practice problems in Ruby and this has come up often.

Let's say i'm trying to solve for the third greatest integer in an array of integers

```
def third_greatest(nums)
  first = 0
  second = 0
  third = 0
  i = 0

  while(i < nums.length)
     if nums[i] > first
       third = second
       second = first
       first= nums[i]
     elsif nums[i] > second
       third = second
       second = nums[i]
     elsif nums[i] > third
       third = nums[i]
     end
   i+=1
 end
 return third
end
```

This code does satisfy the tests cases provided

The solution given however initializes the variables with nil and makes an extra check in each if statement if the variable is nil

```
def third_greatest(nums)
  first = nil
  second = nil
  third = nil

  idx = 0
  while idx < nums.length
    value = nums[idx]
    if first == nil || value > first
      third = second
      second = first
      first = value
    elsif second == nil || value > second
      third = second
      second = value
    elsif third == nil || value > third
     third = value
    end
   idx += 1
  end

  return third
end
```

In what cases is my code incorrect? Which code is better practice? It feels more cumbersome in case 2 though I can imagine there are edge-cases where my solution might not work.

Comment: What if the array of numbers contained a 0? Should that count?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for negative numbers. And:

```
$> nil > -1
NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

That's the reason for nil checks in the second case

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect when the third greatest integer is less than 0, or when the array is shorter than three.

The second code is better, although it is still not good. Making the second code more Rubyish can be like this:

```
def third_greatest(nums)
  a = []
  nums.each do |i|
    if    !a[0] || i > a[0] then a.insert(0, i)
    elsif !a[1] || i > a[1] then a.insert(1, i)
    elsif !a[2] || i > a[2] then a.insert(2, i)
    end
  end
  a[2]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Say nums was `[0,-5,8,-15]`. Zero would be ignored, so you'd have the third biggest as -15, rather than -5 as it should be.

In general, nil is better to assign as if you assign an arbitary value that could be assigned by your code, the logic/flow may break.

IMO both versions of the code above are horrible.

Just `nums.sort.reverse[2]` should get your value or if you want the third biggest unique value: `nums.uniq.sort.reverse[2]`